# ImageMagick NodeJs WriteBlob error

Tags: node.js, imagemagick

I am using the [s3-uploader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3-uploader) module for nodejs to create several versions of an image before uploading to S3. This module relies on ImageMagick to be installed. However, I am receiving this `WriteBlob` error when the command runs.

The files are written to one of the project directories, and I've set permissions correctly. It's been a tricky one, and I believe I've exhausted google :p

Here's the error produced when I print out a nodejs spawn log.

```
spawn called
{ '0': 'convert',
  '1': 
   [ '/home/ec2-user/se/uploads/allergies-infographic-custom.jpg',
     '/home/ec2-user/se/uploads/allergies-infographic-custom.jpg.mpc' ] }
150529/235556.528, [error], message: Command failed: convert: magick/blob.c:4031: WriteBlob: Assertion `data != (const unsigned char *) ((void *)0)' failed.
```

What could this error indicate that I've configured wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I've already gotten the same issue as yours. That problem came from **ImageMagick** library, switch to **GraphicMagick** will solve the problem, because [s3-uploader](https://github.com/Turistforeningen/node-s3-uploader) does not provide option to make the switch, you need to clone that project and modify it manually.

Edit file **index.coffee** and compile it again. Change line:

```
gm = require('gm').subClass imageMagick: true
```

to:

```
gm = require('gm').subClass imageMagick: false
```